# What is the etymology of 'agorism'?

Tags: etymology

Google can't find it anywhere on its [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=agorism&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share&direct_url&direct_url=)

I don't want to use [Wikipedia's claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agorism) as fact and am looking for other sources.

> Agorism is a libertarian social philosophy that advocates creating a
>   society in which all relations between people are voluntary exchanges
>   by means of counter-economics, thus engaging with aspects of peaceful
>   revolution. It was first proposed by libertarian philosopher Samuel
>   Edward Konkin III in 1975.

Comment: Try Google Scholar https://scholar.google.com/  since this appears to be a word that doesn't make it to normal literature but only into academic journals.

Comment: If Wikipedia claims that Konkin coined the term, the obvious place to look is in his works. Try 'samuel edward konkin iii new libertarian manifesto pdf'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The claim is disputed. Someone else claims to have use it first. Wikipedia is a great starting point, but should never be accepted entirely at face value.

Comment: @developerwjk Are you sure? I tried sorting by date, but it only showed 12 results, the earliest being 2015. I happen to know it came before that. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?scisbd=2&q=agorism&hl=en&as_sdt=0,30

Comment: I didn't say that you should accept what Wikipedia says as necessarily true. I said you should follow up possible leads they give.

Comment: Interesting, although google ngram shows nothing, if you search it on google books it finds books.  You can also search agorist.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth OK I looked at the PDF http://agorism.info/docs/NewLibertarianManifesto.pdf but the date says 1983 in the front with a 1980 signature towards the end, referencing a book from 1979 by someone else. Would that mean Wikipedia is wrong?

Comment: ***The term was coined by Konkin.  Konkin's treatise New Libertarian Manifesto was published in 1980.***  Previously, ***the philosophy***  had been presented in J. Neil Schulman's science fiction novel Alongside Night in 1979. https://wiki.mises.org/wiki/Agorism

Comment: @J O S H Does the SH stand for Sherlock Holmes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know the word "Agorism" first appears in Samuel Edward Konkin III's *New Libertarian Manifesto*, published in 1980; but "agorist," "Agorist," and "agoristic" all first appear in my novel *Alongside Night*, published in 1979.

Answer (score -1):

possibly derived from agora, a gathering place esp' an ancient Greek marketplace ( see virtually any dictionary )

Comment: Hi Daniel. You might be right, but did you read the other answer, from the author who actually invented the first use of the term "agorist"? I think your answer would have been better as a comment on that answer. You can add comments once you've participated a bit more on the site and earned the "reputation" (points).